# Laravel9 Kyslik / column-sortable I want to default some sorting to desc

Tags: laravel-9

Laravel9 sorting functionality has been introduced by Kyslik/column-sortable.

I am using "New Listings" and "ABC" sorting.
I would like to sort only "New Listings" by desc.

Currently, when you click on "New Listings", the URL is sort=created_at&direction=asc.
I would like to change this to sort=created_at&direction=desc, but I don't know how.

How can I use Kyslik/column-sortable to make some sorting default to desc?

Controller

```
public function company_list()
{
$company_total = User::all();
$users=User::sortable()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
return view('/company-list',compact('users','company_total'));

}
```

view

```
<p class="companies-content__order-by-link link-asc">@sortablelink('created_at', 'New Listings')</p>
<p class="companies-content__order-by-link link-asc">@sortablelink('company_name_abc', 'ABC')</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config/columnsortable.php you will find

```
/*
default direction for: $user->sortable('id') usage
 */
'default_direction'             => 'asc',

/*
default direction for non-sorted columns
 */
'default_direction_unsorted'    => 'asc',
```

You can change the default sorting from here.